# php function no longer recognizes variable defined outside of it

Tags: php, function, variables

i am relatively new to php and i've encountered a very strange problem.
let me just give an example of a really simple code

```
$test = 'test';

function test(){
    echo $test;
}

test();
```

in the above example, it used to work just perfectly fine, returning 'test' as a result of calling the test() function. however, just today it started to return error saying the variable $test is undefined. i am 100 percent sure it worked just fine before. is this some update in php? or am i doing something wrong here? i am using wamp and testing this on my localhost. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, it's called "variable scope"

read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

One of the 'pitfalls' is:

> You may notice that this is a little bit different from the C language
>   in that global variables in C are automatically available to functions
>   unless specifically overridden by a local definition. This can cause
>   some problems in that people may inadvertently change a global
>   variable. In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a
>   function if they are going to be used in that function.

Comment: this is completely new to me. i've been following a login/register php tutorial that made me create 10 other functions that used to call global variabe just fine without stating global inside the functions. but it just suddenly stopped working. do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: No, not really, as you can read in the link I gave you, this is the expected behaviour, so whatever used to happen seems weird.

Comment: is it because of security that i shouldn't use global?

Comment: @HwaSooCho: No, it's because [Global State is Evil](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil). It makes your code unpredictable and untestable. Anyone can change a global variable, which might affect things it shouldn't.

Comment: I'm not really comfortable adding the advice you did, @truth . It's kinda sensible but not something I would add to this question, as it is more of a design problem (this is not a real world example) so i'm not sure it is fitting here.

Comment: @Nanne: That's your choice (as it is your answer) Though I really do think something should be mentioned about global state being evil.

Comment: Thanks! It works! By the way, why did they have to make our life difficult by doing this? Why couldn't they just have allowed all variables outside of a function to be called in it?

Answer (score 3):

It is because it is outside the scope of function. To access variable defined outside function you must use global keyword.

```
$test = 'test';

function test(){
    global $test
    echo $test;
}

test();
```

Please read about variable scope on php manual link here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Don't use globals, pass it to the function as an argument.

Comment: @Truth that was just an option, here we did not talk about what is good and what is bad. global is just another way of accessing it and when it is there you can always use it, though arguments will be better choice.

Comment: What you're saying is like "Someone asks how to retrieve data from the database, so let's answer using `mysql_*` functions, it's just another way" **NO** it's not another way, it's a **bad** way, one that I wouldn't want a new programmer to learn.

Comment: @Truth - his question was about his confusion towards why function is not able to recognize variable defined outside function? I am sure he already know that if he will pass an argument he will be able to access them inside. So it falls under subject variable scope and that is the reason I mentioned link to php manual referring to this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function, you need to declare `global $test;` for the variable test within the function test to have meaning. Further, any variables declared within curly braces {} will be unset upon leaving the scope of braces, not just within functions.

Comment: See my comment on Dharmavir's answer.

Comment: dont be such strict man. He didn't mentioned what to use and what dont.

Comment: Yes, @truth's harshness is uncalled for, but some people think their truth is The Way & have no respect or concerns for other people. The last time I used a global, I completely rewrote the script & used classes. Then the concept for the project was abandoned. It was right, but also a waste of time & effort.